# Selenium webdriver - Python won't click a button on a website

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am not much of a programmer, I just learnt about Selenium and went as far as I could but there is this mistake I can't fix alone so I am asking for help. I am using Python 2.7 in PyCharm.

As of now, I have been using anything.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) to click some buttons in my code as the .click() function always returned me a ElementNotInteractableException error in Chrome for this website. The goal here is simply to clear a text area, insert the list of genes down there and click on this "submit" button. This is supposed to show me an updated table that I want to download.

For this one troublesome button though, nothing works. The thing is, it doesn't even return an error, the code keeps going on as if it indeed had clicked, and it eventually downloads the non-updated table. I tried switching to Firefox, where neither .click() nor .send_keys(Keys.ENTER) worked (I never get an error as well, it just downloads the wrong table). Clicking myself does work and produces the updated table.

Based on other questions I saw here, I tried using ActionChains or scroll_into_view but still, nothing happens. Here is the code :

```py
baseline_url = "http://mtsspdb.noble.org/atlas-internal/3880/transcript/profile/5?charttype=barchart&sessionid=1553076490500118&feature_accs=%20Medtr1g079760.1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get(baseline_url)
driver.maximize_window()

peptides_list = """Medtr4g068220.1
Medtr1g107390.1
Medtr1g018740.1
Medtr5g016470.1
Medtr4g095002.1
Medtr5g004930.1
MT4Noble_020581.1
Medtr1g107395.1
Medtr1g107400.1
Medtr1g107405.1
Medtr1g107410.1
Medtr4g095010.1
MT4Noble_057127.1
"""
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='feature_accs']")))
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='feature_accs']")
text_area.clear()
text_area.send_keys(peptides_list)
time.sleep(1)
troublesome = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form1']/div[8]/div/input")
print troublesome
#scroll_into_view = troublesome.location_once_scrolled_into_view
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(troublesome).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(3)
print "Sucess for x"
```

The html location of this button is

```html
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Do you have any idea on how to click it, and most of all on why it doesn't work ?

Many thanks

PS: As I said previously, it is my first question. Please tell me if I need to update/change something.

Comment: You have missing `div` index please enter and try it again and you can also use xpath find it using classname that will also one solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will definitely work, as I just tried it given your information

```
driver.execute_script("$('#form1').find('.btn-primary').click()")
```

Now, there must be something strange about it finding the element, as Selenium would error if it could not click. So the element we are clicking with the code must not have the events we expect it to have. I am investigating more and will update this with specifics.

Edit:
Interesting. The submit button does not seem to have normal event listeners.

```
getEventListeners($(".btn-primary")[0]);
$._data($(".btn-primary")[0], "events");
```

Both of these return nothing. This would seem to be the cause of the Selenium issue. It isn't triggering the actual submission with its click. Selenium does not use Javascript, and also does not use a real user32.dll (Windows ex) click, so it does not always behave identically to a real click or a javascript click.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it works perfectly ! I am going to have a look at what javascript is because I have no idea. Still, it works and that will do, many thanks. If you find the answer on why it's weird I am very much interested in knowing why because it drove me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the option to click on the button.

Option 1: click using javascript

```
driver.exeucte_script("arguments[0].click();",troublesome)
```

Option 2: Scrolling to element

```
troublesome.location_once_scrolled_into_view
troublesome.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer !
The javascript did work, however I don't know how it actually works, I never used this. Thanks for solving this for me and I will have a look on what it actually is.
I already tried scrolling to element (commented out on my code above) and it didn't work however

Comment: @RLS_Jekyde If you think the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark below the down vote button on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        f'/html/body/div[{i}]/div/div[2]/span[1]/span/span/input').click()
    except:
        pass
```